# Asp.net MVC Razor @foreach + onclick the data gets listet

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, database, razor

I'm working on a Project Tool that lists all the Projects on the Dashboard. Now I want that when I click on the Project that the Data from my Database gets listed on the right site of it.

**Problem 1**

Code:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)


 {
          <tbody>
                  <tr>
                      <td>Project Titel</td>
                      <td>@item.PrjTitel</td>
                 </tr>
           </tbody>
  }
```

With this all the Database Data gets listet, but i just want the Data from one Project not from Project 1,2,3 listet.

How can i make that ?

**Problem 2**

How can i make that the Data gets listet when the User clicks on a Project. 
So if i click on Project 2 the data from Project to gets listet on the right site. See Screenshot -->

[Screenshot of the front page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qxpDF.png)

Comment: According to what I understand you need links of projects in view when client click any project load data for this projec in the right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Projects) {
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>@Ajax.ActionLink("Select","SelectProjects",new { @id=item.ProjectId},new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod="GET",OnSuccess="LoadProjectsSuccess", OnFailure="LoadProjectsFailur",InsertionMode=InsertionMode.Replace,UpdateTargetId= "Projects" },new { @class="btn btn-info btn-table"})</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>}


<div class="row row-equal" id="Privileges"><div>
```

you can use AjaxHelper  if you don't have any information about ajax helper please visit [Ajax Helper](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/asp-net-mvc-ajax-helper/)

```
public ActionResult SelectProjects(int id)
    {
        DemoViewModel model = new DemoViewModel()
        {
            // Your ViewModel
        };
        return PartialView("_ProjectDetails", model);
    }
```

_ProjectDetails Partial View with data you wont to update

Comment: The first code snipet creates a Button called "Select". When i click on it it gives out an error.

Comment: what is the error and make sure 
you have action SelectProjects in you controller